# How to add spaces in helm set switch in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can I add space in `--set` switch with helm command.
I need spaces between `"mongodb://datadog:'${DB_PASSWORD}'@%%host%%:%%port%%",` and `"replica_check": true,` and also between `"replica_check": true,` and  `"additional_metrics": ["metrics.commands","tcmalloc","top","collection"]}]'`

It gives me error as :
 `that set cannot end with ,`

````
helm upgrade myservice helm/charts/myservice \
-f helm/charts/chat/values.yaml \
--set "mongodb-replicaset.podAnnotations.ad\.datadoghq\.com/mongodb-replicaset\.instances"='[{"server": "mongodb://datadog:'${DB_PASSWORD}'@%%host%%:%%port%%", "replica_check": true, "additional_metrics": ["metrics.commands","tcmalloc","top","collection"]}]' \
--wait --install```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to pass something really complicated like that, it might be easier to package it up in a YAML file and pass it with the `helm upgrade -f` option.

```yaml
mongodb-replicaset.podAnnotations.ad.datadoghq.com/mongodb-replicaset.instances: >-
  [
    {
      "server": "mongodb://datadog:passw0rd@%%host%%:%%port%%",
      "replica_check": true,
      "additional_metrics": ["metrics.commands","tcmalloc","top","collection"]
    }
  ]
```

(The `>-` marker is YAML syntax causing the following indented block to be processed as a string, folding newlines into spaces, and trimming leading and trailing newlines.)

Since valid JSON is valid YAML, if you're trying to launch this from a script, you could use your language-native JSON serializer.

```python
import json, os
db_password = os.environ.get('DB_PASSWORD')
instances = [{
  "server": "mongodb://datadog:" + db_password + "@%%host:%%port",
  "replica_check": True,
  "additional_metrics": ["metrics.commands", "tcmalloc", "top", "collection"]
}]
annotations = {
  "mongodb-replicaset.podAnnotations.ad.datadoghq.com/mongodb-replicaset.instances": json.dumps(instances)
}
print(json.dumps(annotations))
```

Once you've done this you can pass the generated file to the `helm upgrade -f` option.  (You don't need to include the chart's own `values.yaml` file, Helm includes this by default and your values override it.)

```
helm upgrade myservice helm/charts/myservice \
  -f mongo-dd.yaml \
  --wait --install
```

Yet another option is to generate this inside the chart itself.  Helm includes an undocumented `toJson` template function; you can construct objects using the Sprig [`dict`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) function.

```
{{- $server := printf "mongodb://datadog:%s@%%%%host%%%%:%%%%port%%%%" .Values.mongodbPassword -}}
{{- $metrics := list "metrics.commands" "tcmalloc" "top" "collection" -}}
{{- $instance := dict "server" $server "replica_check" true "additional_metrics" $metrics -}}
{{- $instances := list $instance -}}
mongodb-replicaset...instances: {{ toJson $instances }}
```

Your error message suggests your problem isn't the spaces *per se*, but that `helm --set` treats commas as separators between multiple key/value pairs.  You can [backslash-escape the commas](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set)

```
... --set 'mongodb-replicaset..."replica_check": true\, "additional_metrics": ["metrics.commands\,"tcmalloc"\,...]}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the entire connection string in a variable and access it in a shell script.

1. Create a varaible (use escape `\` before commas `,`)

   export MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING="your cs with spaces, and escape commas"
2. Create a shell script

   helm upgrade myservice helm/charts/myservice 
   -f helm/charts/chat/values.yaml --install 
   --set mongodb-connection="${MONGO_CONNECTION_STRING}"